# usage of relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

Are these both correct?

1. Tom was wearing a hat that was too big for him.
2. The hat Tom was wearing was too big for him.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yup. They're both correct and they both come from the same simple clauses. And they're not the only correct combinations, either; _which_ can be used instead of _that_ in (1), though one of them is required (no deletion of subject relative pronouns), and either _which_ or _that_ can be inserted after _hat_ in (2). Since the relative pronoun isn't the subject of the relative clause, it can be deleted.

Comment: Incidentally, note that "that" is not a relative pronoun but a subordinator.

Comment: Note also that "that" nevertheless acts precisely like a relative pronoun, and is generally treated as one by most people's grammars. The POS on its ID card is not checked.

Comment: But it doesn't act like a relative pronoun. CGEL gives several solid and plausible reasons for classifying it as a subordinator.